# laravel 5.4 How do I get current user through User model? and Auth::user() dosen't work

Tags: mysql, laravel, authentication, model, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to get the current user through User model but it returns null.

```
$user = new User;
//$user = Auth::user();
$product = new Product;

$product->user_id = $user->user_id;
$product->save();
```

This is what I get
[Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AykqF.png)

When I tried to get it with Auth::user(), it gives same error.

This is my custom login controller..

```
public function auth(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255',
        'password' => 'required|min:6',
    ]);

    $data = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if (Auth::attempt($data)) {
        $email = $request->email;
         $users = DB::table('users')
            ->where('email', $email)
            ->select('users.*', 'user_name')
            ->get();

        Session::put('set', $users);

        if ($users[0]->is_admin == '1') {
            return redirect()->intended('adminDashboard');
        }else{
            return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
        }
    }else{
        return back()->withInput()->witherrors(['Email or password did not match!']);
    }
}
```

What's wrong with this  code?

Comment: Please provide `Login Controller` code. You have done so many things unnecessary

Comment: You can see the login controller in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try: `$product->user_id = Auth::id();`

Comment: I'm logged in. This controller is only be accessed if you are logged in. You can see the updated question.

Comment: This answer could be more complete if you describe the problem, provided a solution, and explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
$product->user_id = $user->user_id;
```

to this:

```
$product->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
```

Or use relationship to create a product:

```
auth()->user()->product()->create($productData);
```

Comment: ERROR: Trying to get property of non-object.

Comment: @ishanshah are you sure you're logged in? When you're logged in, `dd(auth()->user())` should return logged in User object.

Comment: Try instead `auth()->user()->user_id`

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin yes I'm logged in. But I wonder why it returns null. This controller can't be accessed if the user is  not logged in.

Comment: @NarendrasinghSisodia Tried that as well.

Comment: @ishanshah the route for this action is in `web.php`? Or some custom route file? Do you use `auth()->user()` in a controller method or in a controller constructor?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Yes route is in web.php. I use auth()->user() in a method. Can you please check my updated question?

Comment: @ishanshah try to sign out, change code to `if (Auth::attempt($data)) { dd(auth()->user()); ....` and login again. Does it show you User object when you're loggin in? Does it show `null`? Or it's just redirecting?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Yes it returns some user array like this: User {#206 ▼
  #fillable: array:8 [▶]
  #hidden: array:2 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:11 [▶]
  #original: array:11 [▶]
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #events: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #rememberTokenName: "remember_token"
}

Comment: Then `auth()->user()` should work in a controller for an authenticated user too unless you modified `Kernel.php` or did something similar.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin But dd(auth()->user()->id) returns null. No changes in Kernel.php. How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you get current user details than user bellow code.

```
$loggedInUser = Auth::user();
```

Insert details in user table

```
$loggedInUser['data1'] = $data1;
$loggedInUser['data2'] = $data2;
$loggedInUser['data3'] = $data3;
```

Save user details

```
$loggedInUser->save();
```